# address_space, context macros in compiler.h

Tags: linux-kernel

How to understand the below macros found in include/linux/compiler.h.Mainly, address_space, context macros.

> ```
> 7 # define __user         __attribute__((noderef, address_space(1)))
> 8 # define __kernel       __attribute__((address_space(0)))
> 9 # define __safe         __attribute__((safe))
> 10 # define __force        __attribute__((force))
> 11 # define __nocast       __attribute__((nocast))
> 12 # define __iomem        __attribute__((noderef, address_space(2)))
> 13 # define __must_hold(x) __attribute__((context(x,1,1)))
> 14 # define __acquires(x)  __attribute__((context(x,0,1)))
> 15 # define __releases(x)  __attribute__((context(x,1,0)))
> 16 # define __acquire(x)   __context__(x,1)
> 17 # define __release(x)   __context__(x,-1)
> 18 # define __cond_lock(x,c)       ((c) ? ({ __acquire(x); 1; }) : 0)
> 19 # define __percpu       __attribute__((noderef, address_space(3)))
> 20 #ifdef CONFIG_SPARSE_RCU_POINTER
> 21 # define __rcu          __attribute__((noderef, address_space(4)))
> 22 #else
> 23 # define __rcu
> 24 #endif
> ```

Comment: Refer to [__user macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521551/what-are-the-implications-of-the-linux-user-macro) and [GCC attribute syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

Comment: The key point in [compiler.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/compiler.h) is the `#ifdef __CHECKER__`.  Google **sparse**; a program checker.  Normal Linux compilation doesn't use this.

Comment: I have referred this GCC page, but could not see the any pointers on noderef, address_space() and how they help here.