# Twisted usage of *const* after variable name in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, constants

Can somebody explain what is actually defined in the following code, as well as what is const at the end? Is a variable named `__user` and a pointer `__argv` of type `__user` created?

```
const char __user *const __user *__argv
```

I am familiar with the possibilities of placing `const` (make pointer/data unmodifiable), but I've never thought of the above possibility.

The snippet is from this function declaration in the kernel:

```
1593 int do_execve(const char *filename,
1594         const char __user *const __user *__argv,
1595         const char __user *const __user *__envp,
1596         struct pt_regs *regs)
```

EDIT: I probably wouldn't have asked the question had I known about the `__user` macro before. Still, it's not exactly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521551/what-are-the-implications-of-the-linux-user-macro) because the actual type of defined variable is not discussed there.

Comment: I would assume `__user` is actually a macro of some kind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the implications of the linux \_\_user macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521551/what-are-the-implications-of-the-linux-user-macro)

Comment: If you're curious why it might use `const char *const *` instead of `const char **`, see [Why am I getting an error converting a Foo** → const Foo**?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion) in the C++ FAQ. Basically, converting from `Foo**` to `const Foo**` is unsafe and illegal, but `Foo**` to `const Foo* const*` is safe.

Comment: Do not add tags at random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `__user` is a macro providing some attributes (more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521551/what-are-the-implications-of-the-linux-user-macro)). So, the variable is named `__argv`, which is of type *pointer to const pointer to const char*.

Answer (score 0):

`const T *p` and `T const *p` declare `p` as a pointer to `const T`.

`T * const p` declares `p` as a `const` pointer to `T`.

`const T * const p` and `T const * const p` both declare `p` as a `const` pointer to `const T`.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for downvote, seriously?

Comment: Because I didn't address the `__user` part of the question, I guess.

Comment: Accepted the other one because it gives a reference to the macro in addition to explaining the type of variable defined (I didn't downvote yours).