# macro in function argument

Tags: c, macros

Can you explain me this piece of code ? what does __user here mean ?

```
int create(struct mystruct __user *arg) {
  void __user *user_config;
}
```

(I only post part of the function)
Any reply is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Should have searched [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4521551/2173917)?

Comment: you are right. Thanks a lot. I didn't know where to search :(

Comment: You were not able to enter `linux __user` in the google search mask? First result is the dup. If that was not offending, I'd ask if you are a politician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells the kernel developers that the pointer is user supplied, so it shouldn't be trusted and needs to be validated before operating on.

There are many such definitions in Linux kernel.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse#Linux_kernel_definitions

Comment: Just asking, how come the dupe I pointed did not cover this?