# What is the meaning of argument type: "const char __user *const __user *argv"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls, execve

I see this kind of type in the execve syscall:

```
asmlinkage long sys_execve(const char __user *filename,
const char __user *const __user *argv,
const char __user *const __user *envp);


do_execve(struct filename *filename,
const char __user *const __user *__argv,
const char __user *const __user *__envp)
```

What is the meaning of

```
const char __user *const __user *
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the implications of the linux \_\_user macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521551/what-are-the-implications-of-the-linux-user-macro)

Comment: So it is gcc and linux kernel specific?

Comment: Very much so to my knowledge

Answer (score 3):

As you read through the list of `file_operations` methods, you will note that a number of parameters include the `string __user`. This annotation is a form of documentation, noting that a pointer is a user-space address that cannot be directly
dereferenced. For normal compilation, `__user` has no effect, but it can be used by
external checking software to find misuse of user-space addresses.

Comment: Add link to adequate documentation for reference