# How to interpret address_space struct in `# define __percpu __attribute__((noderef, address_space(3)))`

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel

I am looking scheduling algorithm in

`static void __sched notrace __schedule(bool preempt)` ([__schedule](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.4/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L3259))

Along the way, I find `# define __percpu    __attribute__((noderef, address_space(3)))` ([address_space](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.4/source/include/linux/fs.h#L388))

However, I cannot understand why `struct address_space` can be initialized by using round brackets`( )` since I look through struct syntax in c language.

[How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards) `struct` should be initialized by `{ }` for each filed.

[image: struct of address_space]

#### So, what does `address_space(3)` mean?

Comment: Here `address_space` is an **attribute** of gcc. Its intention is to differentiate `per_cpu` pointers from "normal" pointers for *checker* tools. See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521551/what-are-the-implications-of-the-linux-user-macro) which describes `__user` type modificator for user-space pointers.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So, in another word, the `address_space` is totally not what [struct address_space](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.4/source/include/linux/fs.h#L388), the website gives a wrong index ...?

Comment: The website says that there is `address_space` structure, defined in `linux/fs.h`, but it doesn't imply, that exactly this structure is referenced in `__percpu` definition. Given website provides identificator references with basic knowledge of C language. In most cases this reference is sufficient for navigate between type/function/variable usage and its definition. But the website is completely unaware about gcc specifics. E.g., `__attribute__` is a *keyword* in gcc.